# No muestra código HTML en php

Tags: php, html

Estoy empezando con PHP y no muestra un h1 en mi index.php. Estoy utilizando XAMPP.

```
<h1>Codigo HTML</h1>

<?php
    echo "<h1>Codigo PHP</h1>";
?>
```

Ese es mi código,  y lo muestra como tal en el index.php. También soy nuevo aquí, por si cometo algún fallo preguntando.

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama tu archivo y qué extensión tiene? ¿Cuando dices que te lo muestra *tal cual* a qué te refieres? ¿Cómo se ve la URL del archivo en el navegador?

Comment: He probado tu mismo código en un archivo .php y me funciona correctamente.¿Cómo estás testando que funciona?  Seguramente te falte configurar Apache o Nginx para que se ejecute el PHP.

Comment: Fijate que tu archivo debería tener extensión `.php` y que el servidor tenga el módulo de PHP activado para que pueda interpretar PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate estar corriendo desde el localhost, tu código funciona sin problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]